# How would I connect rigid pvc to a flexible hose for a drain

Tags: plumbing, drain, pvc

I've got two pvc drain pipes in our basement that I'd like to route to the drain. Right now they're pouring out on the floor which is *not great*.

The large pipe says it's a 2 inch pvc pipe (though I measured the outer diameter of the pipe and it's more like 2.5 inch) and the other pipe isn't labeled, but it's outer diameter is 1.5 inch.

I know that I should get some kind of a coupler and connect the PVC to hoses to run to the drain, and I've found some couplers and hoses, but I'm not sure what kind of coupler and hose to use for this case because there are *a bunch* to choose from.

Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar situation with my condensate drain. Original setup was around the walls to the laundry tub - low slope pipe (not PVC - some sort of lesser plastic) that really didn't work very well (probably worked better 60 years ago when it was originally installed). I replaced it with PVC in a more direct route, ending on top of the floor drain.

Why do you need flexible hose? If the pipes are essentially stable, get/cut (very easy with PVC) pipe and connectors so that you end with an output down into the floor drain. Flexible hose may be a bit easier initially but is more likely to get messed up - moved to the wrong location, pinched, etc.

Comment: My thought with the flexible hose was mostly trying to shortcut the "I don't know what parts I need and how to measure them properly" problem. You bring up good points about the flexible hose being easier to mess up. 

I'll try to plan it out rigidly and pipe it into the drain.

Comment: Measure the end (inner and outer diameter) of the existing pipes and go to Home Depot/Lowes/hardware store and find pipe, couplings, elbows, etc. to match.